# Glue as an object

Tags: r, r-glue

I'd like to use the output of the glue function as an R object, but it only works as character.

Example: if I try this -

```
as.factor((
  str_glue("iris$`{colnames(iris[5])}`")
))
```

The result is this:

```
[1] iris$`Species`
Levels: iris$`Species`
```

But I want this:

```
as.factor(iris$`Species`)


[1] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
 ...
[145] virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica 
Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
```

Comment: @Waldi The OP already said the desired output is `as.factor(iris$Species)`.  It is implied that the actual example involves user input or function in which `colnames(iris[5])` is dynamic.

Comment: Thus looks like a case where you should be avoiding glue and parsing. If you want to use a dymamic column name, don't use `$`, use `[[`. For example `as.factor(iris[[colnames(iris[5])]])` will give you the value you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `eval` and `parse` or `parse_expr`:

```
my_str <- str_glue("iris$`{colnames(iris[5])}`")   # glue object

class(my_str)
[1] "glue"      "character"

eval(parse_expr(my_str)) %>% as.factor

[1] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
 ...
[145] virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica 
Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
```

Comment: @Waldi From your link "Of course, `eval(parse())` has its great value and I’m not saying it should be banned." Given the context of the question, I'd say this is an good example of usage.  An alternative might be using `mutate`, `!!sym()` and `pull`, but that would change the OP's code a lot.  Feel free to add a different answer.

Answer (score 1):

Could just do it with `rlang::eval_parse`:

```r
rlang:::eval_parse(stringr::str_glue("iris$`{colnames(iris[5])}`"))
#>   [1] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
#>   [7] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
#>  [13] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
#>  [19] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
#>  [25] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
#>  [31] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
#>  [37] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
#>  [43] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
#>  [49] setosa     setosa     versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor
#>  [55] versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor
#>  [61] versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor
#>  [67] versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor
#>  [73] versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor
#>  [79] versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor
#>  [85] versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor
#>  [91] versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor
#>  [97] versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor virginica  virginica 
#> [103] virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica 
#> [109] virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica 
#> [115] virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica 
#> [121] virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica 
#> [127] virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica 
#> [133] virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica 
#> [139] virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica 
#> [145] virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica 
#> Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Or simply just take the fifth column with `[[` which is the same as taking the fifth column name with ``` $`` ``` :

```r
rlang:::eval_parse("iris[[5]]")
#>   [1] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
#>   [7] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
#>  [13] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
#>  [19] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
#>  [25] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
#>  [31] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
#>  [37] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
#>  [43] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
#>  [49] setosa     setosa     versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor
#>  [55] versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor
#>  [61] versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor
#>  [67] versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor
#>  [73] versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor
#>  [79] versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor
#>  [85] versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor
#>  [91] versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor
#>  [97] versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor virginica  virginica 
#> [103] virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica 
#> [109] virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica 
#> [115] virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica 
#> [121] virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica 
#> [127] virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica 
#> [133] virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica 
#> [139] virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica 
#> [145] virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica 
#> Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>